# Fairness in Optaplanner, but with hours instead of shifts

Tags: java, optaplanner

Im having some trouble with my fairness constraint, I want to make sure employees get:

- Even amount of shifts during weeks.
- Even amount of shifts in total.

Basically I want to avoid that fairness is only checking weeks (so that if there's 2 extra shifts, it won't be the same two employees getting those every week, potentially)

And I want to avoid fairness checking only the total (so that maybe one employee get much more shifts one week, then none the next, but overall theyd all still get even hours)

So I tried to follow what the docs for Optaplanner said in regards to a fairness constraint, and made two constraints for that, but unlike the docs preview that uses shifts, I need mine to be estimated in hours... So now, my code:

```html
public int accumulateFairnessInHoursPerEmployeePerWeek(Week week)
    {
        //System.out.println("WEEK FAIRNESS CONSTRAINT:");
        int actualWorkload = 0;
        int totalAssignmentsDuringWeek = 0;
        for(Employee emp : getEmployees())
        {
            List<Assignment> assignmentsForEmployeeDuringWeek = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Assignment currentAss : getAssignmentsForSpecificWeek(week))
            {
                if(currentAss.getEmployee() == emp)
                {
                    assignmentsForEmployeeDuringWeek.add(currentAss);
                }
            }
            totalAssignmentsDuringWeek += getDurationForAssignments(assignmentsForEmployeeDuringWeek)/3600;
            actualWorkload += (int) Math.pow(getDurationForAssignments(assignmentsForEmployeeDuringWeek)/3600, 2);
            //System.out.println(emp.getName() + " has " + getDurationForAssignments(assignmentsForEmployeeDuringWeek)/3600 + " hours. Score: " + actualWorkload + " total: " + actualWorkload + " " + ass.getShift().getStartDate());
         }
        int idealWorkLoad = (int) Math.pow(totalAssignmentsDuringWeek, 2)/getEmployees().size();
        //System.out.println("IDEAL: " + idealWorkLoad + " ACTUAL: " + actualWorkload + " FAIRNESS: " + (actualWorkload -idealWorkLoad));
        return (actualWorkload - idealWorkLoad);
    }

    public int accumulateFairnessInHoursPerEmployeeInTotal()
    {
        System.out.println("TOTAL FAIRNESS CONSTRAINT:");
        int actualWorkload = 0;
        int totalDuration = 0;
        for(Employee emp : getEmployees())
        {
            List<Assignment> assignmentsForEmployee = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Assignment currentAss : getAssignments())
            {
                if(currentAss.getEmployee() == emp)
                {
                    assignmentsForEmployee.add(currentAss);
                }
            }
            totalDuration += getDurationForAssignments(assignmentsForEmployee)/3600;
            actualWorkload += (int) Math.pow(getDurationForAssignments(assignmentsForEmployee)/3600, 2);
            System.out.println(emp.getName() + " has " + getDurationForAssignments(assignmentsForEmployee)/3600 + " hours. Score: " + actualWorkload);
        }
        int idealWorkLoad = (int) Math.pow(totalDuration, 2)/getEmployees().size();
        System.out.println("IDEAL: " + idealWorkLoad + " ACTUAL: " + actualWorkload + " FAIRNESS: " + (actualWorkload - idealWorkLoad));
        return (actualWorkload - idealWorkLoad);
    }
```

And here's the drools:

```html
rule "EvenWorkloadPerEmployeeTotal"
    when
        $service : Service
        (
            $service.accumulateFairnessInHoursPerEmployeeInTotal() != 0
        )

    then
        if(isDroolActivated(kcontext.getRule().getName(), $service))
        {
            setDroolRating(scoreHolder, kcontext, $service.getDroolStrength(drools), $service.accumulateFairnessInHoursPerEmployeeInTotal());
        }
end

rule "EvenWorkloadPerEmployeePerWeek"
    when
        $week : Week()
        $service : Service
        (
            $service.accumulateFairnessInHoursPerEmployeePerWeek($week) != 0
        )

    then
        if(isDroolActivated(kcontext.getRule().getName(), $service))
        {
            setDroolRating(scoreHolder, kcontext, $service.getDroolStrength(drools), $service.accumulateFairnessInHoursPerEmployeePerWeek($week));
        }
end
```

It seemingly works most of the time, especially in smaller datasets... However, when I use a bigger dataset...
This is my results:

---

- A has 76.0 hours. Score: 5776
- B has 118.0 hours. Score: 19700
- C has 76.0 hours. Score: 25476
- D has 83.0 hours. Score: 32365
- E has 88.0 hours. Score: 40109
- F has 72.0 hours. Score: 45293
- G has 68.0 hours. Score: 49917
- H has 64.0 hours. Score: 54013
- I has 96.0 hours. Score: 63229
- J has 94.0 hours. Score: 72065
- K has 92.0 hours. Score: 80529
- L has 67.0 hours. Score: 85018
- M has 98.0 hours. Score: 94622
- N has 95.0 hours. Score: 103647
- O has 101.0 hours. Score: 113848
- P has 90.0 hours. Score: 121948
- Q has 93.0 hours. Score: 130597
- R has 108.0 hours. Score: 142261
- S has 124.0 hours. Score: 157637
- T has 116.0 hours. Score: 171093

IDEAL: 157560 ACTUAL: 171093 FAIRNESS: 13533

The numbers go pretty high...
And I doubt anyone finds it fair that G and H gets only 64-68 hours, but S must work for 124 hours
I'm wondering if theres another/better way to estimate fairness when using time instead of shifts to calculate fairness?

EDIT: Probably worth noting that I tried with days as well, but the numbers seemed far too small using those, it was like it didn't care much for a single day too much on one employee compared to another.

I'm using these constraints at the same time, but not with other constraints involved

Comment: Did you ever solve this? if so, please share the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tennis example, specifically [this line](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/tennis/solver/tennisScoreRules.drl#L75).

```
rule "fairAssignmentCountPerTeam"
    when
        accumulate(
            $t : Team()
            and accumulate(
                TeamAssignment(team == $t);
                $assignmentCount : count() // This could be a sum of hours too
            );
            $result : loadBalance($assignmentCount)
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, - (int) $result.getMeanDeviationSquaredSumRootMillis());
end
```